# Vim, edit file on quit (delete numbered marks; make :marks easier to use as a bookmark menu)

Tags: vim

In the pursuit of leveraging default functionality in Vim (i.e., less plugins), I am trying to use global marks as a way to jump quickly to my favorite files.

I do this with my "menu" a la

```
nnoremap <leader>l :marks<CR>:norm! `
nnoremap <leader>Lm :marks<CR>:mark<Space>
nnoremap <leader>Ld :marks<CR>:delmarks<Space>
```

The numbered marks make this 10 times harder to skim visually. Alas, it seems there is no option to remove. I have skimmed `:help mark-motions`, `:help viminfo-f` and considered section `# File marks:` at `~/.viminfo`. It seems I cannot remove the functionality of `[0-9]` marks without removing that of `[A-Z]` marks.

If I just delete the numbered marks, I will only have to see the `'0` mark in my "menu". Am I missing some awesome reason to keep the numbered marks around? Is a vimscript to delete the numbered marks on quit or start a bad idea? Is there a safer way to get Vim to not write these to the viminfo file?

Not that this is Emacs, but is there a way to see how the existing `:marks` command works? Or is there something like Emacs' advice to modify how `:marks` will behave?

(Idea: make a command that when `<leader>Lr` is typed, the numbered marks are removed, so that it is "safer".)

Comment: Have you taken a look at exuberant ctags? It might do what you want in terms of jumping to code?

Comment: @FDinoff, I've not gotten around to the "learn to program" todo (nor the "go figure out how ctags work" rabbit hole). Do exuberant ctags apply well to general editing? The about page seemed to focus on programming. I have seen mention of placing tags manually in general files, but that seems awkward for my use case. Also, does it have naming. That is something I can't get from `marks`. Though, `'V` and similar are pretty convenient for jumping to `.vimrc` and other favorites. (`tech.org`, `main.org`, ...)

Comment: Maybe not. I don't know your use case. But jumping to constructs that ctags recognize is really not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the question leads to the answer.

I have

```
nnoremap <leader>Lr :delmarks 0-9<CR>
```

for now. I suppose it would be safe to simply have vimrc execute this on startup.

```
au VimEnter * delmarks 0-9
```